# Are using the Mobile Express Checkout Library or Mobile Payment Libraries PCI Complaint

Tags: paypal, pci-compliance

I'm am trying to figure out which approach I should take when integrating Paypal into my iPhone application. Currently I am not using any of the Paypal libraries in my app. Instead I'm using a UIWebview to open up a url to the Paypal's website and having the customer checkout from there.

I'm wondering if using the Mobile Express Checkout Library or Mobile Payment Libraries are they PCI Complaint. And where can I find documentation that states this on the Paypal's site or Developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about documentation, but as both of these methods ensure PayPal collects the card data, it's for PayPal to be PCI compliant.